# Infinite versus unendlich and double-negation

Tags: soft-question, infinity, philosophy

The German term for infinite is unendlich, which transliterates as non-ending, or non-finite.

This is just word-play but from a constructive point of view, is the shift from a negative to a positive concept of infinity consequential? (one could similarly contrast, eg, discrete versus non-continuous or other dichotomies).

Concretely, is there a logical distinction between the proposition "$p$ is not-infinite" versus "$p$ is not non-finite?"

It would seem that the latter, but not the former, is a pseudo-truth, as defined by Kolmogorov in his paper on the principle of excluded middle (EM) as the double negation of a proposition.

Motivation for considering this comes from basic observations:

- Both set theory and topos theory typically include an explicit axiom of infinity.
- In Moschovakis' *Descriptive Set Theory* the axiom of Infinity is defined in terms of the existence of a set that contains the empty set and the union $x \cup \{x\}$ for any $x$ in this set.

Moschovakis' definition clearly generates an unending diversity of nested sets. However is that the same thing as an actual infinity (constructively, this process would never end).

Comment: "Infinite" also translates to non-ending or non-finite, since  "in-" is a negating prefix in Latin.

Comment: Good point. I'm aware of that (I grew up in Italy) yet somehow the negation seems internalized in "infinity" as a sort of habituation.

Comment: I'd like to add that the correct uninflected form of the adjective would be "unendlich" rather than "unendliche".

Comment: @AndyBrandi, thanks - edited.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, ok so there's no difference between the Latin and German in terms of the negation. But doesn't the question remain as to the constructive validity of ~infinite = ~~finite, which is not constructively equivalent to finite without the Excluded Middle principle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are willing to accept that:

1. Sets cannot be both finite and infinite.
2. Something is infinite, if and only if it is not finite.
3. Everything is either finite or infinite.

Then to say that $p$ is not-infinite is the same saying $p$ is finite and it is the same as saying that $p$ is not non-finite.

Philosophically speaking, we can ask what is finite? Does finite mean equinumerous to a finite ordinal? Without the axiom of choice one has to make the distinction $|A|\nless\aleph_0$ vs. $\aleph_0\nleq |A|$. This gives a little space for a "philosophical" debate for what is infinite.

Do we define infinite sets as not-finite, or do we require them to have some combinatorial property (such as a bijection with a proper subset; or even just a surjection from a proper subset; and more). Regardless to how you define it there are two things which seem indisputable:

1. The finite ordinals are finite, no matter how you choose to define finiteness.
2. Anything which contains a countably infinite subset is infinite.

As for constructive infinite, I heard they are still constructing that...

---

I want to add a tangential story. Yesterday on my way back from Jerusalem I met someone which is a hobbyist mathematician and a finitist. He believes there is meaning to the phrase "all the natural numbers" or "all the even numbers", but there are no such sets.

We discussed that it's easier to express infiniteness. You just need to assert that something is infinite. However to show something is finite you need to actually bound it. In this aspect there is one trivial schema of first-order axioms which assures infiniteness (add the sentence "There are $n$ distinct elements", for every $n$); but there is no such schema which assures finiteness.

Comment: Asaf, are your initial points 1. 3. true without EM and also the negation of both sides of 2?

Comment: I think Dedekind wrote in an unpublished letter (I'd like that reference) something to the effect that the bijection to a proper subset is the *only* rational definition of infinite. (Elsewhere he also credits that definition to Bolzano and Cantor.). My question there is, when is the *proper* part constructively decidable? Eg, in Collatz conjecture: is the basin of attraction of $(4,2,1)^\infty$ cycle a proper part of the naturals?

Comment: I don't know what is "true". In what sort of context? As for the definition of infinite, I find that if a set can embed all the finite ordinals then it must be infinite. Even if it cannot embed them all uniformly. In this aspect I much prefer Tarski's definition of finite to that of Dedekind: $A$ is finite if and only if every non-empty collection of subsets of $A$ contains a $\subseteq$-maximal element.

Comment: What's the relation of Tarski's definition to Dedekind's? Ps, are you familiar w/ this paper "Independence of various definitions of finiteness" by Levi:  http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm46/fm4611.pdf

Comment: Tarski's equivalent to "true" finiteness without choice, whereas Dedekind's definition requires some choice. If you replace $\subseteq$-family by $\subseteq$-chain then you need some choice, but less than the amount required to show that every Dedekind-finite is finite.

Comment: Can you please send me one or two references to Tarski's definition that compares it to RD's?

Comment: It's late, I'll try to find the references tomorrow and leave a comment. But what's RD?

Comment: Ok thanks.. RD = Dedekind

Comment: Any luck w/ the references? Are there Tarski-finite sets that are not finite in the "ordinary" sense? Are there T-finite sets that are not D-finite? Vice versa?

Comment: Yes, I haven't had time to write the comment, but Tarski's paper is in French, "*Sur les ensembles finis*" (a link appears in the Wikipedia page for "Finite sets"). The paper itself shows that the equivalence "*$A$ is finite if and only if for every non-empty family of subsets of $A$ there is a maximal [or minimal] $\subseteq$-element*" holds in ZF. If one replaces family by $\subseteq$-chain then the $\Rightarrow$ implication requires a bit of choice, let us call such sets T-finite sets. [cont.]

Comment: [...] It is true in ZF that T-finite is D-finite, and the implication D-finite is T-finite is equivalent to D-finite is finite. This is because if there is an infinite D-finite set, then there is one which is not T-finite. But there are models where there are no infinite T-finite sets, but there are infinite D-finite sets. If you have Jech's "*The Axiom of Choice*" you can search for T-finite and find such exercises scattered around the book.

Comment: Very cool thanks. Who knew there would be so much complexity in the seemingly basic property of being finite.

Comment: If you are interested there is a paper by Truss (from about 1964 or so) which studies Dedekind-finite sets according to the division proposed by Levi (I think). It is quite thorough and has a listing of several (if not all) possible subdivisions of finiteness of these classes. And yes, when the finite gets infinite, everything goes haywire...

Comment: Staying within the world of the finite, how are these considerations operationalized in (increasingly generalized) definitions of *combinatorial species*, the simplest being endofunctors $\bf B \to \bf B$ (finite sets and bijections)? Does it make sense to talk about full subcategories etc?

Comment: Within the world of finite everything is meaningless because there is only one kind of finiteness. As for talking about functors and categories, for me it's not natural at all and it never made sense anyway...

Comment: I meant within the *various* notions of finiteness: numerical vs. D-finite, T-finite.. in other words, some objects (sets) are in the D-finite sets but not finite. So how are they related is the question.

Comment: Ps: In the study of mental mathematical constructions, "to exist" must be synonymous with "to be constructed" in fact, mathematics, from the intuitionist point of view, is a study of certain functions of the human mind.
- Heyting "Intuitionism, an introduction" 1956

Comment: It is always the case that D-finite is the maximal sense of finite, and finite is always the minimal case of finite. This much was covered in my answer. But between the different classes of finiteness there are complex relationship of inclusions and possible equalities. To read me you can review the main results in Truss' paper, if you don't follow the proofs it's a quick and interesting read. As for the Heyting quote, my degree is in mathematics, not neuroscience nor psychology. I don't see why I should study the human mind and its functions. I prefer mathematics.

Comment: Ok thanks, will seeks the Tarski and Truss papers. There's also a one by Herrlich that discusses the maximality of D-finiteness. So it is like a lattice with discrete and indiscrete topologies at the extremes? -- Re Heyting quote, there's a comment in Goldblatt's *Topoi* to the effect that we solve equations or inverse images the pullbacks have to be constructed and it's very different than the set theory conception. I think that speaks volumes - the solution is implicit until constructed, it is not "given".

Comment: Also, can you explain what you mean by: "He believes there is meaning to the phrase "all the natural numbers" or "all the even numbers", but there are no such sets." Aren't $\mathbb{N}$ and $\{ x \in \mathbb{Z}  |  mod(x,2)=0 \}$ sets?

Comment: No. They are classes. As much as I gather the guy works internally to the universe of hereditarily finite sets. So you can have induction over the naturals, and you can define subclasses of the naturals, but they don't form a set.

Comment: What prevents $\mathbb N$ from forming a set?

Comment: If your universe consists only of those sets which are hereditarily finite, then there are no infinite sets. The last time I checked, $\mathbb N$ was infinite.

Comment: Ok that I understand. They're not objects in $\bf FinSet$. (I thought you were going to say they are classes rather than sets.)  But what kind of relation or axiom is "hereditary"?

Comment: It means that all the elements are finite, their elements are finite, and so on.